# Whitespaces and not-standard symbols in paths in arguments for split utility (cygwin)

Tags: python, windows, split, cygwin

I want to split my `tar` archive and send all its parts to a server. If I use the `split` utility on *nix it works fine, but if I use it on windows `(Cygwin)` I need to write paths like

```
C:\Имя Пользователя\
```

with Russian letters and whitespaces. 
It doesn't work. 
On the console - I see this callback:

> split: cannot open '"C:\Users\'$'\320\224\320\274\320\270\321\202\321\200\320\270\320\271'' '$'\320\237\320\260\321\201\320\265\321\207\320\275\321\216\320\272''\Downloads\1\table1488120407.9.csv.tar.gz"' for reading: No such file or directory

Using `""` doesn't help either.

Comment: have you tried to move/copy the file in a directory that does not contain space like `/tmp` and then split it ?

Comment: For some reason `r"C:\Users\Дмитрий Пасечнюк\Downloads\1\table1488120407.9.csv.tar.gz"` is being encoded as UTF-8 and written in escaped octal. If it's something Cygwin does; it's weird to do it on an NTFS filesystem. You'll be better served using native utilities that use the wide-character API with UTF-16 filenames.